# http is working good. But https not working and redirecting to other domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have domain and sub domains. I have purchased and applied a SSL certificates to my domains. Anyway one of my sub domain is not working with https://. But it is working perfectly with http://.

I dont know why. I suspect the htaccess file. But it is clearly good. Can you please help me on this ?

I have checked the online SSL verifier for the sub domain. The sub domain is trusted site only. But not working with https://

htacess:

```
Satisfy Any
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Technology of the site is **WORDPRESS**.
SSL is from **GoDaddy**

Please help me.

Comment: try by write this `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R,L]` just before closing tag of `</IfModule>`

Comment: ThankYou Raunak. But its not working.

Comment: Actual problem is when i use https its shows error 301 (Moved permanently error), after that url redirected to another domain.

Comment: But when try http:// it working good. and not showing 301 error.

Comment: have you set the `home_url` and `site_url` with https version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar situation and this is what I did:

Go to ***Dashboard -> Settings -> General*** and do the following:

- WordPress URL: https://example.com
- Site URL: https://example.com

Please note above that it is https and not http

Additionally, I also installed this plugin called:
**Easy HTTPS (SSL) Redirection** - https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/

After installing this plugin, go the settings of this plugin and do the following:

- Check the ***Enable automatic redirection to the "HTTPS"***
- Check ***Apply HTTPS redirection on*** based on where you need to apply this
- Check ***Force resources to use HTTPS URL***

> **Note from the developers:** If you're using caching plugins similar to W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache, you need to clear their cache
>   after you enable or disable automatic redirection option. Failing to
>   do so may result in mixed content warning from browser.